# Added new fields to JSON API but not visible in Ember inspector store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, ember-data

I added some new fields to a model and updated my JSON API etc.. The fields are definitely in the JSON output. I updated my ember model and my templates as well. The new fields are not visible looking at the data source in the Ember inspector in Chrome. I have no idea why. I don't think I missed anything but I must have missed something. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Without showing the json/model definitions it's near impossible for us to guess what may be be wrong.

Comment: fair enough.. in fact I missed a property in my serializer and that is what was wrong. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: coolio, glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. I had a malformed JSON string. As soon as I fixed it the new properties were all picked up. Sorry for the false alarm.